# Why the different plots?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

Solving a system of trigonometric equations

```
Reduce[Sin[x] + Sin[y] + Sin[z] == 0 && Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] == 0 && 
x > -Pi && x <= Pi && y > -Pi && y <= Pi && z > -Pi && z <= Pi, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

, I obtain a long and complex  result. In order to verify the result, I draw it (The execution takes more than one hour
on my comp.) by

```
r = ImplicitRegion[Reduce[Sin[x] + Sin[y] + Sin[z] == 0 && Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] == 0 &&
x > -Pi && x <= Pi && y > -Pi && y <= Pi && z > -Pi && z <= Pi, {x, y, z}, Reals], {x, y, z}]
Region[r]
```

[image]

The result should  coinside with the result of

```
t = ImplicitRegion[Sin[x] + Sin[y] + Sin[z] == 0 && Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] == 0 && 
x > -Pi && x <= Pi && y > -Pi && y <= Pi && z > -Pi && z <= Pi, {x, y, z}]
Region[t, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, BaseStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

, but it is not true. I think the result of `Reduce` is not correct. How to correctly solve this system?

Comment: I think that the reason is the `Region` and `DiscretizeRegion` are not so robust. For example: `reg = ImplicitRegion[{((x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 2) && 
        x + y > 0 || x - y < 0 && .5 < x < .8) && 2 y > x^2}, {{x, -2,
      2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
GraphicsRow[{reg // Region, reg // DiscretizeRegion}]`

Comment: @cvgmt: Did you look at the output of `Reduce[Sin[x] + Sin[y] + Sin[z] == 0 && Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] == 0 && 
x > -Pi && x <= Pi && y > -Pi && y <= Pi && z > -Pi && z <= Pi, {x, y, z}, Reals]`? Its solution by hand produces a quite simple result.

Comment: @cvgmt: Sorry, I don't understand the relation between your example and my question. Can you elaborate your comment? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 I believe cvgmt is simply saying that the problem is likely due to flaws in `ImplicitRegion` and/or `Region`, not in the output of `Reduce`, and is giving an example of `ImplicitRegion` and `Region` behaving badly. It does seem that there are artifacts from the drawing process in your picture. however, when I evaluate the `Reduce` expression, I get a warning, so there might be a problem there too.

Comment: @thorimur: Unfortunately, your claim " It does seem that there are artifacts from the drawing process in your picture." is not grounded. I also obtain a warning "Reduce::ztest: Unable to decide whether numeric quantities {Sqrt[3]-Root[{-3+Power[<<2>>]&,3+Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<2>>]&},{2,3}],-Sqrt[3]+Root[{-3+<<1>>^2&,3+<<5>>+3 <<1>>&},{2,3}],<<1>>,Sqrt[3]+Root[{-3+Slot[<<1>>]^2&,3-4 Slot[<<1>>] Slot[<<1>>]-2 Power[<<2>>]+4 Slot[<<1>>] Power[<<2>>]+3 Power[<<2>>]&},{2,1}]} are equal to zero. Assuming they are."  before the output.

Comment: @user64494 is not "grounded"? what do you mean? Those look like numerical artifacts to me.